# "the stir and keep of pride" in G.M.Hopkins' poem

Tags: meaning, poetry

From [The Habit of Perfection](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Habit_of_Perfection) by Gerard Manley Hopkins:

> Nostrils, your careless breath that spend
>
> Upon **the stir and keep of pride**,
>
> What relish shall the censers send
>
> Along the sanctuary side!

What is *the stir and keep of pride* here? Stir = commotion? Keep = stronghold (metaphorically, the body)? And what they may mean combined in one sentence?

I understood the bit with censers that send fumes along the wall of the refuge, but the first half of the stanza is misty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. B. Martin, in *[Victorian Poetry](http://books.google.com/books/about/Victorian_poetry.html?id=JHk_AAAAIAAJ)* (p. 768), glosses *keep* as *maintenance* (that is, with its sense as in *upkeep*).  Note that reading *keep* as work and effort is consistent with reading *stir* as bustle and bother.  Both those readings are consistent with the apparent intent of *careless breath* and *pride*.

Comment: Thanks, jwpat7! *Keep* as *upkeep* seems reasonable and does away with my uncertainty concerning the use of the slang sense of *stir*. Reminds me of my other question, regarding a poem by  Guy Wetmore Carryl where the author mercilessly cut *angleworm*, leaving only *angle*.

Answer (score 1):

Stir here means prison (as in Stir Crazy) and keep is a stronghold/fortress, yes. Having read the full poem I think it's associating the sense of smell with pride in the sense of pridefulness/aloofness/disdain. Maybe reminiscent of "turning your nose up at something" or sniffy/sniffily.

Comment: Thanks, Mathemagician! The Century Dictionary mentions the "prison" sense for *stir* but adds a parenthesized note, "Thieves' slang". Should'd been quite a fresh slang word in 1880s; I'm unsure whether he could had mixed in a (then vulgar?) novelty with antique "noble" words like keep, censers, sanctuary.

Comment: A prison and a fortress are two sides of the same coin ... keeping things inside or outside. The poem dates from 1866 apparently, however the word had already been used in print by Henry Mayhew in _London Labour and the London Poor_ according to this [blog](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/09/in-stir.html). That's the sort of earnest Victorian writing that Hopkins might have read.